# Android build failing for React Native

Tags: android, react-native

While creating android build with following command 
`./gradlew assembleRelease`

it fails with following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':awesome-project' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
```

Same issue if I try to clean android build `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the Kotlin plugin to the specified version?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your Kotlin version in your project level build.gradle file. If you have it configured the usual way, you should have the following line in it around the top:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2'
```

To upgrade to the version matching your plugin, simply change this line to:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'
```